# Rpi 4 not booting after adding new i2c bus. changes made in config.txt

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-4, i2c, boot-issues

I made changes in config.txt to add a new i2c bus to connect a serial display as a temperature sensor is already connected to the default i2c bus.
I took the following steps:

1. Enabled i2c in Rpi configuration.
2. Added the following line at the end of config.txt

dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=4,i2c_gpio_delay_us=1,i2c_gpio_sda=23,i2c_gpio_scl=24

Also my etc modules shows i2c-dev
and Rpi 4 VERSION_ID="10"

following is my config.txt:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

# NOOBS Auto-generated Settings:
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128

dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=4,i2c_gpio_delay_us=1,i2c_gpio_sda=23,i2c_gpio_scl=24
```

**Update** with info from a comment:
I tried following things:

1. remove changes in the config.txt (which is just 1 last line) then it booted normally.
2. reinstalled default os version of Rpi from recovery mode, which resulted in the same problems again after a clean setup and changes in config.txt. Neither of them solved the problem.

Comment: Have you tried a new clean copy of Raspbian to see if the Pi boots?  I would remove all additional hardware, download a new copy of Raspberry Pi O/S (I normally use lite at this point as it’s quicker) and then boot from that.  You then know it’s either hardware or software...

Comment: I tried following things:
1. remove changes in the config.txt (which is just 1 last line) then it booted normally.

2. reinstalled default os version of Rpi from recovery mode, which resulted in the same problems again after a clean setup and changes in config.txt.

Neither of them solved the problem.